# When is the Russian letter "o" pronounced [a]?

Tags: произношение, буквы, ударение, редукция-гласных, диалект

Sometimes, the Russian letter **o** is pronounced [o], but other times it's pronounced [a]. How do I know when to pronounce it [a]?

Comment: Say 'o' and people will think that you are from Vologda and this it. In a year or so you will adjust to local dialect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest rule is to determine whether the syllable with *o* is stressed or not. In stressed syllables, it's pronounced [o], while in non-stressed syllables, it's pronounced closer to [a] (although not necessarily pronounced the same as stressed *a*).

A good summary can be [found here](http://diktory.com/bezud_a_o.html) (in Russian).

It's worth noting that whether or not vowel reduction is actually used in speech depends on the dialect. For example,  [this English wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okanye) has some more information. Note that the two Russian versions of the articles - [оканье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) and [аканье](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5) - give a more thorough explanation than the English version.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably the most famous phonetic phenomenon in Standard Russian. It's called "аканье" (akanye, "ah-ing") and it's a form of vowel reduction. Tons of materials are available on the subject, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction_in_Russian#Back_vowels) has [lots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology#Unstressed_vowels), too.

In summary, the letter 'o' *in an unstressed syllable* is pronounced like "a" and realized phonetically as [ɐ] in the syllable immediately preceding the stressed syllable, and as [ə] in other unstressed syllables. Stressed "o" is always pronounced [o]:

> молоко́  - [məlɐ'ko]

You can pronounce both [ɐ] and [ə] as a pure [a] and it won't sound foreign to the Russian ear.

Answer (score 3):

Ukrainian is very close to Russian, and here, we say [ko'rova] and [molo'ko] without reducing the unstressed o's in any way. You'll find this pronunciation in a lot of Russian dialects as well.

Comment: I've never heard any Ukrainian speakers' *okan'ye*, though, when they speak Russian. they have different dialect marers but not that one, meaning that these are not directly related.