# Should the "о" in Russian be pronounced as a short "a"?

Tags: произношение, ударение, редукция-гласных

Should the "о" in Russian be pronounced as a short "а" (like a short "a" in English)?

Comment: Related: 1. [Why do some people pronounce "о" as "a" and some just pronounce "o" as "o"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/17243/why-do-some-people-pronounce-о-as-a-and-some-just-pronounce-o-as-o) 2. [When is the Russian letter "o" pronounced \[a\]?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/when-is-the-russian-letter-o-pronounced-a)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if unstressed. And if by "short /a/" you mean both [ʌ] and [ə].

This is a mainstream dialect which became a norm over the course of many years. Still, there may be some local dialectal differences.

Answer (score 4):

To be more precise, after a non-palatalized consonant, the pronunciation of unstressed "o" is reduced. This is called *аканье* (akanye) in Russian. It's quite an old phenomenon which can be traced back at least 500 years. There's a Wikipedia article on it, and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akanye) particular quote is especially relevant:

> In Russian (except for Northern dialects), /o/ and /a/ phonetically merge in unstressed positions. If not preceded by a palatalized (soft) consonant, these phonemes give [ɐ] (sometimes also transcribed as [ʌ]) in the syllable immediately before the stress and in absolute word-initial position.<sup>[6]</sup> In other unstressed locations, non-softened /o/ and /a/ are further reduced towards a short, poorly enunciated [ə]. After soft consonants, unstressed /o/ and /a/ are pronounced like [ɪ] in most varieties of Russian (see vowel reduction in Russian for details); this reduction is not considered a manifestation of akanye. Unlike Belarusian akanne, Russian akanye does not affect softened vowels.

As a side node, we actually encounter the same thing in a lot of English dialects where, say, "stop" is pronounced as [stʌp].