# Pronunciation of лаборатория

Tags: произношение

[I've been told](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/when-is-the-letter-o-pronounced-as-a) that **о** is pronounced as **а**  when it's not stressed, however  the word **лаборато́рия** [is actually pronounced](https://forvo.com/word/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F/#ru)  **лабо́рато́рия** , why is that?

Comment: As a side note. With such complex words people may inadvertently pronounce them  syllable-wise (more or less smoothly). In this case o->a transition not always occur.

Comment: the real answer is that your assumption is wrong and it's not pronounced that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really, it's indeed to be, and is, pronounced `лАбАрАтОрия` or in the Moscow pronunciation as can be heard in some of the clips `лАбрАтОрия`

Answer (score 7):

The word *лаборатория* [is pronounced](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F#Pronunciation) as [ləbərɐˈtorʲɪjə] and it has only one stressed vowel sound. The effect you hear is due to the fact that the [ə] of the first letter 'O' really sounds more like [o] than like [a] because [ə] is not as open a sound as [a].

Comment: Did you mean `[ləbərɐto'rʲɪjə]`? Stress on second а sounds wrong.

Comment: @alamar - I have everything right. In transcription the stress mark is put _before_ the stressed syllable, _not after_ the stressed vowel. _Many_: [ˈmænɪ], _begin_: [bɪˈgɪn], etc.