# Why is по pronounced "po" but по русски is pronounced pa-ruski? Or am I saying one of them wrong?

Tags: выбор-слова, произношение, редукция-гласных

Literally, the very first thing in Russian that I learned was the phrase "я не очень хорошо говорю по русски" so I know that по русски is pronounced pa ruski, but I was adding a pronunciation for the word по on Anki and it's actually po and not pa? Am I saying something wrong?

Comment: Unstressed "o" is reduced to "а" as well as "е" to "и".

Comment: This is a feature of a [Moscow accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscovian_dialect), the most common accent in Russia.

Comment: "O" in an unstressed position is reduced to something between "o" and "а" or to clear "a" sound, depending on a position in a word, speakers accent and even how fast they talk. It's really a schwa sound. It's not unlike most US accents, think of words like "chocolate" (second "o") or "memory". In fact many vowels in Russian are not pronounced clearly when they are in an unstressed position. There are a plenty of questions and answers here regarding that

Comment: This is one of the frequent questions that has been answered numerous times, see for example:  [When is Russian 'O' pronounced as 'A'](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/when-is-the-letter-o-pronounced-as-a)

Comment: why nothing is pronounced `nʌθɪŋ` and not `noθɪŋ`?